# Does Opera 10.6 properly support border-radius on fieldsets?

Tags: css, border, opera

I am trying to get the border radius property to work properly on a fieldset in Opera 10.6, but it does not appear to be working correctly.

Here is the html:

```
<form method="post" action="character.php" class="form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Insert</legend>
        <label for="txtCharacter">Character</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtCharacter" name="txtCharacter" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the css I am trying to use:

```
.form fieldset {
    background-color:#355e3b;
    margin:0px;
    border:3px solid #635147;

    /* Adds the rounded border effect. */
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

The above works perfectly in Firefox and Safari, giving a me a rounded fieldset with desired border shape/size/color and the correct background color:

[Safari http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/8411/safari1.png](http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/8411/safari1.png)

Opera gives me the correct colors, but the borders are square:

[Opera1 http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/2051/opera1r.png](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/2051/opera1r.png)

However, if I take the line specifying the border (`border:3px solid #635147;`) then Opera gives a rounded fieldset just as it is supposed to:

[image: Opera2]

What's going on here?  Why won't Opera display the border-radius when a border is selected?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a bug in their rendering engine.

Comment: I wondered that too, I was just curious if anyone else had noticed it.

Comment: I just filed a bug report on their site. Maybe Opera 10.7 will works as expected. ;)

Comment: It's fixed in the today's nightly. Will be available in Opera 12.

"CORE-35190 (CSS: border-radius ignored on fieldsets that have a legend)"

Answer (score 1):

There are a few well know issues with [rounded corners on input elements in Opera](http://blog.attrakt.se/2010/04/annoying-opera-css3-bug-input-border.html), possibly one of the workarounds people have discovered for that would work on your fieldset.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input.  I at least feel like I'm not crazy now!

Comment: Yeah, it's good to have resources on such things. However, the bug mentioned is fixed now (I just tried).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Opera 11.51, and the bug is still there.

css:

```
fieldset {
    moz-border-radius:1.5em;
    border-radius:1.5em;
}
```

Chrome, Safari, Firefox: works

IE 6 thru 8, Opera 11.51: doesn't work (no support until IE9, of course).

Comment: It's fixed for Opera 12. Just a little bit longer to wait.. :)