# Opera 12 does not hide content with border-radius

Tags: html, css

Maybe I am too stupid but I do not understand why Opera 12 does not have the desired behaviour. I created a minimal sample:

```
    <div id="outer" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="inner" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: red;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The outer container has a border-radius. All content in the inner div that overlaps the outer one has to be dropped. This is done with "overflow: hidden".

This works perfectly in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari. The only browser that does not behave like that is Opera. I tested Opera 11 and 12.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Opera 10.6 properly support border-radius on fieldsets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461201/does-opera-10-6-properly-support-border-radius-on-fieldsets)

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3463475/1190388

Comment: @hjpotter92 There's no `fieldset` here

Comment: @Mr.Alien But the bug is still here.